# w3wp process memory rises with each request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, w3wp

I have a sample ASP.net web api project, which I have created using the VS template.I haven't made any changes to the code inside.  I notice that the memory usage by the w3wp process for this one keeps increasing when I call the same controller multiple times. It returns me the same view but the memory keeps increasing by  MBs. Is this normal to behave like this?

Comment: Perhaps you could tune (or explicitly invoke) the garbage collector

Comment: This [link](https://wrightdev.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/memory-leak-within-xmlserializer-6) was very helpful